# CRC calculation of executable code

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, crc32, win64

I have an application in which  some code integrity check procedure is used. Integrity check looks like the following:

```
  codemark1_start:

   <Some code>

    codemark1_end:
    AsmCrcCodeMrk((MyTinyBuff), codemark1_start, codemark1_end, 1,Procedure);
```

**AsmCrcCodeMrk  macro  looks like**

```
AsmCrcCodeMrk(DescriptorAddr, StartAddr, EndAddr, Id, BPA)  \
        AsmCrcCodeSig                                           \
        __asm mov EAX, offset DescriptorAddr                    \
        __asm mov EAX,  StartAddr                           \
        __asm mov EAX,  EndAddr                         \
        __asm mov EAX, Id\
       __asm mov EAX, BPA\
```

After compilation, the program has been processed by an additional application that "pulls out" the fragments between labels and calculates theirs CRC.
Under Win32, everything compiles and works.

**However, for X64 there are difficulties:**

**1)** X64 does not support inline assembler. But I can make macro as function in separate file and I can make the function __forceinline.

**2)** It is necessary to get addresses of labels at the compilation time. And this is a problem.

Can anyone tell me how to get addresses of labels at the compilation time for X64 platform?

Comment: use separate asm file and compile it with *ml64.exe*. all here is possible. however, if `AsmCrcCodeSig` code not typo - it senseless - simply put `BPA` to `EAX`. all previous instruction lost effect